# Cannot see someone's hat collection on their SO or meta.SO profiles

Tags: bug, winter-bash-2015

Based on a quick sampling of a dozen users over a number of sites, it appears that you cannot see someone's hat collection on their network profile (makes sense) **but**, out of all the other sites and meta-sites, if you navigate to someone's SO or meta.SO profile, there is no option to see their hat collection there. either.

Comment: They likely haven't enabled hats on Stack Overflow. (SO is the only site where a user has to explicitly opt-in)

Comment: Worth to mention that wearing a hat and unticking "wear only on this site" also auto-opting-in on Stack Overflow. /cc @hichris123.

Answer (score 0):

I just went to your SO profile and I can see your hats just fine:

[image: screen shot]